# Margins on responsive design do not work on mobile

Tags: iphone, css, ios, wordpress

I have a responsive wordpress theme and the right site of the site i  off on mobile (IOS).. how can i remedy this?

I have tried the usual minwidth to no avail..

```
.middle {
clear: both;
z-index: 2;
width: 100%;
padding-top: 27px;
min-width:1450px
}
```

http://speedsociety.com/

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your site doesn't appear to be responsive, at least from what I can see. Do you have any media queries set?

[Check out media query syntax](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries)

Edit: I just checked the parent theme stylesheet and there are no media queries set, thus your theme is not responsive.

Comment: Everything but the new div i insterted with the video is responsive.. I dont even need the video to resize, just for the page to scroll all the way right on mobile